# Sencha app not loaded in Windows store package

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, extjs, windows-10

Exactly as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699025/sencha-app-doesnt-start-in-windows-app-package), we have an extjs app + cordova that runs fine on all platforms including Windows in debug mode, but as soon as packaged, doesn't load anymore.

Since the old question hasn't been updated by the OP and is inactive, I'd like to ask differently:

- Is there a way to force-load a Sencha app manually from javascript? Any entry points in the Microloader?
- Any idea what could be different in the package and how could we trigger loading?

I'm able to attach the Visual Studio Debugger to the app package and it works. Without debugging, it hangs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: The Microloader can be removed and the dependencies loaded using `<script>` and `<link>` tags directly.